# Why a complementary inequality for function values does not simplify to False?

Tags: functions, assumptions, inequalities

I have a general assumption of a function to be positive. The direct inequality (f[x]>0) does simplify to True, but a complementary one (f[x] < 0) does not simplify at all despite the fact that I explcitly assumed that funciton is not zero.

```
$Assumptions = K[_] > 0 && K[_] != 0

FullSimplify[K[15] > 0]
True
FullSimplify[K[12] == 0]
False
FullSimplify[K[15] < 0]
K[15] < 0
```

Thansk in advance,

UPD
Following a comment I tried the same with another function name (f[_]) to avoid possible issues with capital K which is reserved, however the problem persists.

Comment: In Mma the capital `K` is reserved. Therefore, its use in your code is a syntax error. If you change it for a small `k` it will work: `Clear[k]; $Assumptions = k[x_] > 0 && k[x_] != 0; FullSimplify[ k[15] == 0]` yields False

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch a Flase for k[15]==0 is returned for capital K as well, that is no problem, it is k[13]<0 that is not simplified. I tried with anotehr function name f[_], and the problem persists.

Comment: I don't think Mathematica can handle these kinds of assumptions when the assumption contains an inequality. For instance `FullSimplify[f[15] == 3, f[_] < -1]` fails, but `FullSimplify[f[15] == 3, f[_] == -1]` works and returns `False`. You could work around it by replacing `f[15]` and `f[_]` with a single symbol, say `x`, and `FullSimplify[x == 3, x < -1]` behaves as expected.

Comment: @flinty you aere right, for single symbols it does work. However, I do need a function as I plan to apply it to more cumbersome expressions which will be simplified upon several assumptions.